# Flask - get redirected to new page after POST-request

Tags: python, flask, redirect, http-post

I have an edit-button on my Site, that will do a POST-Request and then I want to be redirected to `new.html`, that contains a form, that holds my POST data.

The POST request in my js-file:

```
async function onEditBtn() {
    // find correct entry in schedule
    const data = schedule.find(meeting => meeting.id == rowIdOfContextMenu);
    rowIdOfContextMenu = -1;

    const response = await fetch("editmeeting", {
        method: 'POST',
        body: data});
}
```

The receiving Flask-route:

```
@app.route('/editmeeting', methods=['POST'])
def edit():
    data = request.get_json()
    print(data)
    return render_template('new.html', data)
```

POST request is succesful, but I am not getting redirected to `new.html`.

If I use `window.location.href = "<route to my edit page>";` or `window.location.replace();` on js side using the response I get from the POST request, my edit page won't get the POST-data.

**EDIT**:
What I was looking for was `window.location.href` with POST instead of GET.

I ended up using Flask's session object. Did a POST request to `/editmeeting`, saved the POST-data in a session object, then manually redirected my page to another route rendering `new.html` using `window.location.href` in my js-code, and used the data stored in the session.

Thank you for your aswers!

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: No, i can console.log(response) and it shows some object

Answer (score 1):

You could add GET method to this function

```
@app.route('/editmeeting', methods=['GET', 'POST']
```

or add this to your imports

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for
```

and change the return of the function to something like this (only works when 'new' is indeed a function in your app.

```
return redirect(url_for('new'))
```

Comment: I tried this before. What happens is, that the redirect will send me a Response, but my browser wont change the window.location

Comment: Show us your 'new' function. There might be an issue there.